# Can anyone show me an example on how to add text to a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

Most of the code examples I have seen show images that are added. I am looking for an example that essentially just shows about 10-15 row of data being added to a UIScrollVIew.

Any solid advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out UITextView, its fairly easy to implement, but it might not have the versatility that you want.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html

Answer (score 7):

Put this into: viewDidLoad{}

```
//create UITextView

UITextView *myUITextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,188,280,260)];
myUITextView.text = infoText;
myUITextView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
myUITextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
[myUITextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
myUITextView.editable = NO;
myUITextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
[Scrollerview addSubview:myUITextView];
[myUITextView release];
```

where 'infoText' is your text, and 'Scrollerview' is your uiScrollView